# Android - Sharing HTML to WhatsApp & Email

Tags: java, android, html, css

I would like to create a option in my app to share a HTML generated page to WhatsApp & Email, but i can't seem to be able make it share with formatting (tables are not working).

Is it possible to share HTML with tables and formatting using CSS in WhatsApp and Email?

Another thing is when the pop up asks for what App to share with can I limit what apps to share with. Is it also possible to have certain apps to have different data to share, for example WhatsApp & Email get HTML formatted data but SMS gets plain text?

The Code I'm currently using is:

```
dis = Html.fromHtml(html).toString();

Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("text/html");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share With?");
sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, dis);

if (sharingIntent.resolveActivity(this.getPackageManager()) != null)
{
     this.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share With?"));
}
else
{
     toast("No Sharable Apps Found!");
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is not HTML format of whatsapp message. On the other hand you can send HTML formatted e-Mail. It has some restrictions like you have to use in-line styles. But any how you can send a HTML formatted e-Mail by using `ACTION_SENDTO` intent.

The code look like this

```
final Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("mailto:"));
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The Subject");
shareIntent.putExtra(
Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
Html.fromHtml(new StringBuilder()
    .append("<p><b>Some Content</b></p>")
    .append("<small><p>More content</p></small>")
    .toString())
);
```