# How to send "Styled text" from my app to Whatsapp?

Tags: android

I searched everywhere in the internet but I didn't find any documentation to send styled text from my app to Whatsapp.

Here is my code Which i used to send text from my app to Whatsapp through intent:

```
String s = list.get(index);
            SpannableStringBuilder SS = new SpannableStringBuilder(s);
            int length = s.length();
            SS.setSpan (new CustomTypefaceSpan("", custom_font), 0, length-1,Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE);

            Intent whatsappIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            whatsappIntent.setType("text/plain");
            whatsappIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            whatsappIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, SS);
            try {
                ctx.startActivity(whatsappIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Whatsapp is not installed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

Here is CustomTypefaceSpan class:

```
public class CustomTypefaceSpan extends TypefaceSpan {

private final Typeface newType;

public CustomTypefaceSpan(String family, Typeface type) {
    super(family);
    newType = type;
}

@Override
public void updateDrawState(TextPaint ds) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(ds, newType);
}

@Override
public void updateMeasureState(TextPaint paint) {
    applyCustomTypeFace(paint, newType);
}

private static void applyCustomTypeFace(Paint paint, Typeface tf) {
    int oldStyle;
    Typeface old = paint.getTypeface();
    if (old == null) {
        oldStyle = 0;
    } else {
        oldStyle = old.getStyle();
    }

    int fake = oldStyle & ~tf.getStyle();
    if ((fake & Typeface.BOLD) != 0) {
        paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    }

    if ((fake & Typeface.ITALIC) != 0) {
        paint.setTextSkewX(-0.25f);
    }

    paint.setTypeface(tf);
}
```

}

It only send plain text without style applied on it.
Thanks in  advance.

Comment: I am not sure if Android allows you to send formatted text outside the app scope but here is the link I have found and it is sending HTML text to WhatsApp [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46321027/android-sharing-html-to-whatsapp-email]

Comment: In app https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.whats.textstyle.com.textstyler styled text is sent to whatsapp. Any way thanks for your response.